# How to break the match case but not the while loop

Tags: python, event-loop

I'm trying to use match case when checking the value in event loop. However `break` not only break the match case, but break the event loop too.

This is the code

```py
while True:
    # Some code stuff here
    if event == "#PassSign":
        # Some code stuff again to check password strength
        # Display the password strength
        match strength_pass:
            case 0:
                window["#StatusPassSign"].update("No Password", visible=True)
                break
            case 1:
                window["#StatusPassSign"].update("Password Strength: Low", visible=True)
                break
            case 2:
                window["#StatusPassSign"].update("Password Strength: Medium", visible=True)
                break
            case 3:
                window["#StatusPassSign"].update("Password Strength: High", visible=True)
                break
```

How to break/stop the match case, without stop the event loop?

Comment: You don't need to break match cases.

Comment: You don't need that breaks probably if you don't want them to break the loop.

Comment: You don't need it? I thought it was because JavaScript need the break

Comment: So, as already told, no need for `break` in python match. On a side note, there is also a `continue` token which allow you to stop an iteration without breaking the loop.

Answer (score 11):

There is no fall through in Python, so no need for trailing `break`.

What if you need an early break? You can emulate that with exceptions:

```
class _MyBreak(Exception): pass

foo = 5
bar = 3
try:
    match foo:
        case 5:
            if bar > 1:
                print("about to break")
                raise _MyBreak()
            print("not reached")
        case 42:
            pass
except _MyBreak:
    pass
```

Comment: This is correct.   Remember in Python, `break` statements /can only belong to a `for`  or `while` loop/.   Nothing else.